# How do I build out a mocked hub for Unit Testing SignalR 2.x implementation?

Tags: unit-testing, cookies, signalr, moq, signalr-hub

I'm working on building up Unit Tests for our SignalR 2.x implementation.
Our implementation utilizes accessing request cookies stored in the Context.

So, to build out our unit tests, we have to create a mocked cookie collection
and associate it with the mocked request object.

I've seen the following code block that does this in SignalR 1.x:

```
const string connectionId = "1234";
const string hubName = "Chat"; 
var mockConnection = new Mock<IConnection>();
var mockUser = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
var mockCookies = new Mock<IRequestCookieCollection>();
var mockPipelineInvoker = new Mock<IHubPipelineInvoker>();

var mockRequest = new Mock<IRequest>();
mockRequest.Setup(r => r.User).Returns(mockUser.Object);
mockRequest.Setup(r => r.Cookies).Returns(mockCookies.Object);

StateChangeTracker tracker = new StateChangeTracker();
Clients = new HubConnectionContext(mockPipelineInvoker.Object, mockConnection.Object, hubName, connectionId, tracker);
Context = new HubCallerContext(mockRequest.Object, connectionId);
```

I'm running into issues trying to create the mocked cookie collection.
IRequestCookieCollection above is undefined.

```
var mockCookies = new Mock<IRequestCookieCollection>();
```

Did this move somewhere else in the SignalR libraries?
Or.., is there a different way to do this??

Thanks,
JohnB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SignalR 1.0, the type of `IRequest.Cookies` was changed from `IRequestCookieCollection` to `IDictionary<string, Cookie>`. As part of this change, `IRequestCookieCollection` was removed.

Changing `mockCookies` to reflect to the new type should fix your issue:

```cs
var mockCookies = new Mock<IDictionary<string, Cookie>>();
```

However, it might be painful mocking out an IDictionary, so it is probably easier to use a normal Dictionary instead:

```cs
var cookies = new Dictionary<string, Cookie>();
// ...
mockRequest.Setup(r => r.Cookies).Returns(cookies);
```

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1034

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I figured that out as well. However, I'm having difficulty adding to it. I tried the following code:  cookie = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Cookie("Test", "CookieValue");
mockCookies.Object.Add("Test", cookie); This call is not behaving as expected. If I look @ mockCookies after the "Add," I don't see the entry getting added to the dictionary. What am I missing here?  JB

Comment: Just use a normal Dictionary. I've updated my answer to reflect this.